# Bootstrap 4, change col-xl @media min-width in html styles only

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I would like to set .col-xl min-width for @media to 1600px;
It's there a way to set so in html style only without changing any less or sass files? I just want to leave loading bootstrap from their official bootstrapcnd urls.

Comment: Do you mean for the `.col-xl` class only, or for the entire xl tier (eg; col-xl-1,col-xl-2,col-xl-3,etc..)?

Comment: For the entire xl. I want to have 6 columns (col-xl-2) for browser windows wider than 1600px  and keep col-lg-4 as it is.

Answer (score -1):

You can change that under style tag in your html page.

```
<style> 
   @media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
     .col-xl {
       min-width: 1600px !important;
     }
   }
</style>
```

!important to make it important and override other bootstrap rules. 
If you want to put it inline to html tag.. it is not possible.

Edit: What ever you want to change .. you will have to write it in this given way. Actually bootstrap have other classes also for the whole col-xl grid system. so change that class css also. 
For example for `col-xl-2{ min-width: 100px !important}`

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work.
My columns are
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-2">...</div>

and I added to styles
    @media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
     .col-xl {
       min-width: 100px !important;
     }
   }

So my goal it to have 6 solumns when the width of a browser is more than 1600px. Min-width is not the width for the columns but for the screen.

Comment: write col-xl-2 { min-width: 100px !important} see edit

Comment: You can see working example here.. but its for col-lg-4 only for testing purpose.. you can similarly make your desired changes... https://codepen.io/uuuchit/pen/NvdQGa

Comment: No. It doesn't work. Let me explain more clealy: Bootstrap 4 grid system uses lg for ≥992px and xl for ≥1200px. I want to have 4 columns for browser width up to 1600px (so col-lg-3) and 6 columns for browser window wider than 1600px (col-xl-2)

Comment: @UchitKumar .. I think the OP wants to change the *screen width* for the breakpoint, not the min-width of `col-xl-*` which don't have a `min-width` in the first place.

Comment: @ZimSystem, yes, exactly.

Comment: Now I got your question ... but it will again be done in similar way. I will update my answer soon